# Would $\text{Arg}(-z)$ be harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis

Would the function $\text{Arg}(-z)$ be harmonic everywhere but the positive x-axis?

Comment: I guess the capital A in Arg$(\cdot)$ means the imaginary part of the principal branch  of $\textrm{Log}(\cdot)$?

Comment: yea sorry.Forgot that

Comment: I guess it was understood!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because it is the imaginary part of principal logarithm of $-z$ which is analytic in this region.